ICP Air Handler C wire location
Can someone help me understand where to attach a C wire to this Air Handler ICP Model: BDHU 331000 . The current wire running from the thermostat to the air handler has 6 wires but only 3 being used. It does tie in to the outside unit along the way. There are the 3 connections outside the machine from the thermostat. One black to black, 1 red to red, and one yellow to red.Inside the machine ther are 3 connections, 1 black to green, one red to red and one blue to white.  Any and all help is appriciated
https://photos.fife.usercontent.google.com/pw/AP1GczN6KLM-1VIr5GROI1CX5z6RivRzeRaIg0weDaj1E7SbMB9C0j5zkebtzA=w1239-h929-s-no-gm?authuser=0
https://photos.fife.usercontent.google.com/pw/AP1GczPR0jUzM7rVj68rnVbs8qCtik7Kx64l2IO3ojL5KC2vr4f8KfIyqvLYCw=w696-h929-s-no-gm?authuser=0

Some pics of all the wiring involved would help tremendously.

Gonna try to add pics. I origionaly tried and it said files too big...

I added picture links
